# Two connections on a Riemannian Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, geodesic, connections

Can I have two connections on a Riemannian Manifold compatible with two different metrics and are torsion free(Levi Civita)?. If yes, then are the related or independent?

I am particularly concerned with the pullback connection.

If $\phi:(M,g,\nabla)\rightarrow (N,\tilde{g},\tilde{\nabla})$ is a diffeomorphism and $(\phi^*\tilde{\nabla})_XY=\phi_*^{-1}(\tilde{\nabla}_{\phi_* X}(\phi_* Y))$ is the pullback connection on the pullback bundle over M compatible with the pullback metric $\phi^*\tilde{g}$.

Are these two connection same or $(\phi^*\tilde{\nabla})_XY-\nabla_XY=D(X,Y)$? Is the Pullback bundle same as the bunfle on M? What happens if I take M=N but keep the Riemannian structure different?

Please forgive me If my question is not well framed as I am currently studying this.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "compatible"? Do you mean only that the parallel transport preserves the metric? (In this case, a Riemannian metric does not determine a unique connection.) Or you also require connections to be torsion-free (Levi-Civita)? In this case you get the same connection by the uniqueness theorem.

Comment: @Moishe Cohen Yes you are right, These connections are Levi Civita and hence unique. What am I trying to ask is that whether the pull back bundle is a separate Riemannian structure on M?If not how to see that these to bundles are same?

Comment: Pull-back bundle in this case is isomorphic to $TM$.

Comment: How to prove that?The pull back connection is not compatible with $g$ it is compatible with $\phi^*\tilde{g}$ and $\phi$ is not an isometry i.e. $\phi^*\tilde{g}\neq g$.

Comment: Since $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism, the differential $D \phi : TM \to \phi^* TN$ is an isomorphism. The pullback connection will be compatible with the pullback metric, but usually not with $g$. (In order to make the latter question make sense we must identify the bundles $TM$ and $\phi^* TN$.)

Comment: If $\tilde{\tau}^t_0$ be the parallel transport in N corresponding to the connection $\tilde{\nabla}$. Is $\bar{\tau^t_0}=\phi^{-1}\tilde{\tau}^t_0\phi$ the connection in $M$ corresponding to the pullback connection.